# Ubuntu 10.10 -bash: java: command not found

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssh, jdk, vps

I just bought fresh VPS with Ubuntu 10.10.
I following this guide http://l2jserver.com/wiki/Setup_Server_-_Ubuntu for creating Lineage2 server, but this doesn't matter.
I try to use command `java -version` and I got error:

`-bash: java: command not found`

If I skip this step and use this command (for install Java): `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk` I got this error:

```
Unable to locate package sun-java6-bin
Unable to locate package sun-java6-jre
Unable to locate package sun-java6-jdk
```

What's wrong with It? Thank you for answers.

**UPDATE #1**

When I type: `java -version`

I got error: `-bash: java: command not found`

When I Type: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ maverick partner`

I got error: `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

When I type: `sudo apt-get update`

I got error:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-e                                                                                                 n
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-a                                                                                                 md64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/bi                                                                                                 nary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/bina                                                                                                 ry-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/                                                                                                 binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restr                                                                                                 icted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/unive                                                                                                 rse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/main                                                                                                 /binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/rest                                                                                                 ricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/univ                                                                                                 erse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used                                                                                                  instead.
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list looks like:
[image]

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncomment the two lines in /etc/apt/sources.list that refer to "partner"
Try :

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

replace 'nano' with the installed text editor like vi etc.

uncomment the two lines referring to "partner", (remove the #)

If there's no repository, add one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ maverick partner"
```

Now,

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: In my sources.list are only 3 lines at all and there aren't commented lines : `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted universe
`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates main restricted universe
`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted universe`

Comment: If I type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` I got error: `sudo: nano: command not found`

Comment: If I open etc/apt/source.list by WinSCP this file doesn't have any commented  lines, only 3 lines at all. I'm useing WinSCP and PuTTy and what you mean to replace with nano?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ maverick partner"` sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: 'nano' and 'vi' are text editors for Ubuntu. What I mean by replace 'nano' in the command (when nano is not installed) is that you can instead use a command of the form: `sudo <installed-text-editor> /etc/apt/sources.list` , For Example:  `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`  Where 'vi' is the name of installed text-editor.

Comment: I opened editor Its ok, but that line I added manually and `sudo apt-get update ` doesnt work error: `Failed to fetch not found urls...`

Comment: Maybe I need reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: I reinstalled OS, but the same problem

Comment: I updated my question with detail info.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre, openjdk-6-bin, openjdk-6-jdk

Comment: Thank you for answer, but after this I got error: 
`Unable to locate package openjdk-6-jre `
Unable to locate package openjdk-6-bin 
`Package 'openjdk-6-jdk' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

i had this similar problem this is the problem of the frameworks(pythons,ruby,perl).so i changed the Ubuntu os to 12.04.so the best way to solve this case is the upgrading the os